# Scope issues with javascript (node.js + mongo.db)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am encountering some problems with my convertKey function, and I suspect it is due to scope issues. Basically, I try to retrieve a record from my mongo database and store it in a count variable, but when I try to return it, I get "undefined". Surprisingly,  `console.log(nameSearch + count)` works, while  `return nameSearch + count` doesn't. Would really appreciate it if someone could help me on this!

```
var dbUrl = "kidstartnow",
  collections = ["students", "studentsList"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(dbUrl, collections);

function Student(name, src) {
  this.name = name.toLowerCase();

  //this function does not work
  this.key = convertKey(this.name);

  this.src = src;
  this.pointsTotal = 0;

  //inserts student into database
  var student = {name: this.name, key: this.key, pointsTotal: this.pointsTotal,
    src: this.src
  };
  db.students.insert(student);

  //converts name to a key by stripping white space and adding a number behind and ensures keys are unique
  //concatenates names together to form namesearch, and checks if entry exists in studentsList
  function convertKey(name) {

    var nameSearch = name.replace(/\s/g, ''),
      count = 1;



    db.studentsList.find({name: nameSearch}, function(err, student) {      
      //if nameSearch does not exist in studentsList, create entry and sets count to 1
      if(err || !student.length) {
        db.studentsList.insert({name: nameSearch, count: 1});
        count = 1;
        return nameSearch + count;
      }

      //if entry does exist, increments count by 1
      else {
        db.studentsList.update({name: nameSearch}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("Error incrementing records");
          }

          db.studentsList.find({name: nameSearch}, function(err, student) {
            count = student[0].count;
            //this works
            console.log(nameSearch + count)
            //but this doesn't
            return nameSearch + count;
          });
        });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning from the callback to `db.studentsList.find` and not from your `convertKey` function.

If you want the value to be returned from within `db.studentsList.find`, you'll need to either supply a callback to `convertKey` or possibly use a Promise library to make `convertKey` a deferred/future.  Otherwise, your function will return immediately while waiting for your nested async functions to complete.

A callback allows you to pass on the result you're looking for (e.g. `callback(nameSearch + count)`)

*edit*

Whenever I have questions about the return values of functions, I match braces with comments:

```
function convertKey(name) {

    var nameSearch = name.replace(/\s/g, ''),
      count = 1;

    db.studentsList.find({name: nameSearch}, function(err, student) {      
      //if nameSearch does not exist in studentsList, create entry and sets count to 1
      if(err || !student.length) {
        db.studentsList.insert({name: nameSearch, count: 1});
        count = 1;
        return nameSearch + count;
      } else {
        db.studentsList.update({name: nameSearch}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, function(err) {
          // ...
          db.studentsList.find({name: nameSearch}, function(err, student) {
             // ...
             return nameSearch + count;
          }); // end db.studentsList.find
        }); // end db.studentsList.update
      } // end else
    }); // end db.studentsList.find

    /**
     * Notice, no return value here...
     */
  }; // end convertKey
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Just one quick followup: I tried adding a callback function, and called it as such, but it does not work. Do you know where I am going wrong     this.key = convertKey(this.name, function(text) {
    return text;
  });

Comment: @DanTang I think you need to read up on [Continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and there's a pretty good article [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/). Basically, you'll need to contain all logic relying on the `text` value within that callback function. This is the same idea as what you're doing in the callback passed to `db.studentsList.find`.